# php symfony delete wont work setting up also the routing.yml

Tags: php, ajax, symfony-1.4

Hi i have question regarding the php symfony delete.my javascript and ajax post code is fine. I dont know why it cannot delete to my database. i already targeted and pass the id, and also i already set up my routing.yml. I keep on debugging this but nothing happened.
Here's frontend module seminar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tbl_comments").show();

    //$("#loading").hide();
    $("#ptxt_green").hide();

    $('#comment_form').ajaxForm({  
      target: '.tbl_comments',
      beforeSubmit: validate,     
      success: function(){
        //alert(data);
        $(".tbl_comments").fadeIn('slow');
      }
    });

    $("#loading")
      .hide()
      $(".tbl_comments").show()
      .ajaxStart(function(){
        $(this).show();
        $(".tbl_comments").hide();
        $("#loading").show();
      })
      .ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".tbl_comments").show();
        //$("#loading").hide();
        $("#comment").val("");
      })
    ;

  });

  function validate(){   
    var comment = $('textarea[name=comment]').fieldValue();
    if(!comment[0]){
      $("#ptxt_green").fadeIn();
      $("#ptxt_green").fadeOut(3000);      
      return false;
    } 
  }

  function goDelete(id){
    if(xconfirm()){
      //$('#comment'+id).fadeOut('slow');
      $("#loading").show();
      $.post('<?php echo url_for('seminar/delete'); ?>',{id:id},function(){
        $("#loading").hide();
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<?php $sf_response->setTitle(myTitleFactory::getPageTitle('seminar_detail', 'frontend',array('%seminar_title%'=>$seminar->getTitle())));?>
<?php myTools::loadBreadSlot(array(
  myBreadcrumbFactory::get('seminar-list', 'frontend'),
  myBreadcrumbFactory::get('seminar', 'frontend', array('slug' => $seminar->getSlug()), $seminar->getTitle())))  
?>

    <h1><?php echo $seminar->getTitle(); ?></h1>

    <div class="table_seminar_wrap">
    <table class="table_seminar" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="info table">
      <tr>
        <th>Employee Id</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getId(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">情報公開日</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getPublishDate() .' '.$seminar->getPublishHour(); ?>時</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">セミナースキーム</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getStyle(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">日程</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getSeminarDate() .' '.$seminar->getStartTime() .' ～'.$seminar->getEndTime(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">前振りの文章</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getRawValue()->getSummary(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">タイトル</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getTitle(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">サブタイトル</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getSubTitle(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">開催地</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->_getAddress(ESC_RAW); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">会場</th>
        <td>
          <?php if($seminar->getLocationName()) : ?>
            <?php echo $seminar->getLocationName(); ?><br>
          <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if($seminar->getRoomName()) : ?>
            <?php echo $seminar->getRoomName(); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php if($seminar->getLocationName()) : ?>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">会場URL</th>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $seminar->getLocationUrl(); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><?php echo $seminar->getLocationUrl(); ?></a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">内容</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getRawValue()->getDetail(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">キーチャート</th>
        <td>
          <?php if($seminar->getImagePath()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $seminar->getImagePath(); ?>" target="_blank">
              <img style="width:300px;" src="<?php echo $seminar->getImagePath(); ?>"/></a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">対象</th>
        <td>
          <?php foreach($seminar->getTarget() as $target): ?>
            <?php echo $target; ?>
          <?php endforeach;?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">定員・残席状況</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getCapacity(); ?>人</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">参加料</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getPrice(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">担当者</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getEmployee()->getName(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top">講師</th>
        <td>
          <img class="instructorImage" alt="Instructor Image" src="<?php echo $seminar->getInstructor()->_getImagePath(); ?>" /><br>
          <span><?php echo $seminar->getInstructor()->getName(); ?><span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th valign="top" style="width:170px">ご参加の皆様へのメッセージ</th>
        <td><?php echo $seminar->getRawValue()->getMessage(); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php if($sf_user->isAuthenticated() && !$seminarXPerson): ?>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
            <div class="blueBtnLink">
              <a href="<?php echo url_for('seminar/apply?id='.$seminar->getId()); ?>" title="応募する"><span>応募する</span></a>
           </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <?php elseif(!$sf_user->isAuthenticated()): ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">
          <div class="blueBtnLink">
            <a href="<?php echo url_for('seminar/apply?id='.$seminar->getId()); ?>" title="応募する"><span>応募する</span></a>
         </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
    <div id="ptxt_green">
      <p>Please Write A Comments. . .</p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <?php if($sf_user->isAuthenticated()): ?>
    <form id="comment_form" action="<?php echo url_for('seminar/comment'); ?>" method="post">
      <textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Write Comments" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div id="loading" style="text-align:center;">
        <img alt="" src="/images/loading.gif" />
      </div>
      <div class="result">
        <table class="tbl_comments">
          <tbody>
          <?php foreach($comments as $x => $comment): ?>
          <tr id="comment<?php echo $comment->getId(); ?>">
            <td width="10%">Comments:</td>
            <td>
              <?php echo $comment->getComments(); ?><br />
              <a href="javascript:;" title="delete" onclick="return goDelete(<?php echo $comment->getId(); ?>) " >Delete</a>
              <a href="">Reply</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

and my controller

```
<?php

/**
 * seminar actions.
 */
class seminarActions extends sfActions{
 /**
  * Executes index action
  *
  * @param sfRequest $request A request object
  */

   /* public function preExecute(){
    }*/

  public function executeDelete(sfWebRequest $request){
    echo "test"; exit();
    $id = $request->getParameter('id');
    if($id){
      $comments = Doctrine_Core::getTable('SeminarsComment')->find($id);
      $comments->delete();
    }
    return $this->renderText($id);

    /*$this->id = $request->getParameter('id');
    if(!$this->id){
      $this->forward404();
    }
    $comment = SeminarsCommentTable::getInstance()->find($this->id);
    $comment->delete();
    */
  }
}
```

and my routing.yml

```
seminar_delete:
   url: /seminar/delete
   param: { module: seminar, action: index }
```

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get? Do you see "test" in responce?

First of all your routing should be

```
seminar_delete:
   url: /seminar/delete
   param: { module: seminar, action: delete }
```

Action: `delete`, not `index`

Comment: Its ok now the problem is in my schema.yml, i put 3 primary true to 3 different fields instead only in id, my mistakes thanks anyways